# What does the .map file do in coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

When I am coding in CoffeeScript, my IDE automatically compiles it to JavaScript. It however also creates a sameName.map file with it.

On closer inspection of the map file, it just a lot of random values. Why is it used and is it ok to remove it?

Comment: Look in Google for "Coffeescript sourcemaps". It's a way to track your original Coffee code when debugging.

Comment: Still did not get it.. Is it there so that the CoffeeScript can be debugged?

Comment: See here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that browsers that understand sourcemaps (and have that feature turned on) can use that .map file to backtrack from a line of js to a line of coffeescript. It's not exclusive to coffeescript.